# please provide xpath of the following:

Tags: xpath, uniqueidentifier

What should be the xpath for this object?

```
<td id="searchButtonCol">
    <input id="ctl00_m_EmployeeDirectoryEmployee Directory_ctl00_btnSearch"
           type="submit"
           onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$EmployeeDirectoryEmployee Directory$ctl00$btnSearch", "", true, "", "", false, false))"
           value="Search"
           name="ctl00$m$EmployeeDirectoryEmployee Directory$ctl00$btnSearch">
</td>
```

Comment: I was just doing that, of course. Wouldn't it be better, though, to try to google the issue before posting a question? Every single XPath tutorial will teach you how to locate elements in 5 minutes. Also, the developer tools in every modern browser have an option to "Copy XPath" so that you don't even need to care anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the XPath 1.0 docs, [the `id()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id).

For the `<td>` element, do

```
id('searchButtonCol')
```

For the `<input>` element, do

```
id('ctl00_m_EmployeeDirectoryEmployee Directory_ctl00_btnSearch')
```

Comment: do you mean this:
//td[@id='searchButtonCol'][@id='ctl00_m_EmployeeDirectoryEmployee Directory_ctl00_btnSearch']
 ? Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @rjt What I wrote was a complete XPath expression that you could use to find your elements. What you wrote is almost correct. You'd need to change it to `//td[@id='searchButtonCol']/*[@id='ctl00_m_EmployeeDirectoryEmployee Directory_ctl00_btnSearch']` to be completely okay, though. And because the `id` attribute must be unique, you can safely reduce it to `//*[@id='ctl00_m_EmployeeDirectoryEmployee Directory_ctl00_btnSearch']`. From there, there's just a small step to what I wrote above :).